# How to reset bcdedit /dbgsettings in windows?

Tags: windows, windbg

In my test system, I have  modified busparams as 0.40.0 . Now If I have to reset it to the default value , is there a reset/delete like command which will delete all dbgsettings parameters that are currently set?

Comment: `bcdedit /deletevalue`?

Comment: It worked . Thanks!

Comment: `bcdedit /debug off` I used this to reset debugging. I dont have much experience with bcdedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcdedit -deletevalue {dbgsettings} busparams

Comment: You should wrap your code snippet in backticks (`) to make it more readable

Answer (score -2):

Although (bcdedit /debug off) does reset debugging, but the Windows system still thinks that Kernel Debugger is enabled.

We use a VPN to connect to our Windows activation servers and, native or our Global Protect VPN won't connect with Kernel Debugger enabled.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31261370)